# Memcache Serializable JSONObject?

Tags: java, json, serialization, memcached

I'm using json.org JSONObject. I've tried to serialize it to memcache and got the not so cool `java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json.JSONObject`. Looking at the JSONObject [code](http://json.org/java/org/json/JSONObject.java) it seems that it's nothing more then a Map wrapped by JSON logic. Why not make it serializble then?

I would like to be able to store the object into memcache in an easy interface. Is there a similar API implementation of JSONObject that is also serializble. Alternatively, what memcache friendly serialization / deserialization technique do you use ?

Thank you,
Maxim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/ to be API compatible implementation of org.json.JSONObject. It does not have all the getDouble, getLong, getJSONArray methods but other then that the concepts are pretty much the same.

It excels over org.json implementation by the fact that it simply extends HashMap for JSONObject and ArrayList for JSONArray making these objects by definition serializble and thus cacheable.

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind that Java's Serializable is just one implementation of serializing objects. A JSON object by definition is another method. Any JSONObject can be converted a String by calling String strJSON = jsonObject.toString() and then you can recreate the original JSONObject by calling jsonObject = new JSONObject(strJSON);

Answer (score 5):

`JSONObject`s are meant be sent as simple strings. So instead of storing the Java serialized form of your `JSONObject`s you should store the stringified forms.

Answer (score 3):

if you use org.json.JSONObject, it doesn't implement the Serializable interface. For that reason it can't be serialized. Instead, you can put the String version of JSONObject into MemCache.